# PTX - what is a CTA?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpu, ptx

I'm studying PTX and I don't understand how a CTA (compute thread array) is different from a CUDA block.

Are they the same thing? It seems to me that for now (I'm just at the beginning of the PTX document) they're just the same

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the PTX cooperative thread array is conceptually  and functionally the same as a block in CUDA or a workgroup in OpenCL.

Answer (score 15):

The [Thread Hierarchy](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/#thread-hierarchy) section of the [CUDA PTX ISA document](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/) explains that, essentially, **CTA means a CUDA block**.

Also note that it's actually not a "Compute Thread Array", but rather a "Cooperative Thread Array" (!).

Answer (score 1):

CTA is just another way of saying Threadblock Nvidia calls it CTA.